# Convert InputStream to Mediaplayer

Tags: inputstream, android-mediaplayer

I use android platform . I have file in InputStream Datatybe ,  I want to convert it to MediaPlayer and play it

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. Get the entire input into a properly formatted file, and pass that file to MediaPlayer. You're going to have to figure out if your data is formatted properly and how to format it.
2. Instead of using MediaPlayer, use **MediaCodec** (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) where instead of passing a file or a link you're passing the data itself. With this solution, you're going to have to figure out if you're passing the data properly to Media Codec, but I suspect this is the solution you're looking for. The google documentation does have an example to get you started a bit.

Good luck to you!

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the data? MP4?

If it is a standard container like MP4 and is a file accessible as a URI in local filesystem (file://) or network (http://) then you should use Google's [ExoPlayer library](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), with [demo code here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/demo).

I would only resort to using MediaCodec if you have a custom container or transport mechanism.